# ¿Cómo centrar un jPanel dentro de un desktopPane?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un punto de venta pero al agregar el jPanel no lo centra bien no se como arreglarlo alguna ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jDesktopPane1.removeAll();
    soldProd sold = new soldProd();
    sold.setBounds(jDesktopPane1.getBounds());
    sold.setVisible(true);
    //sold.setAlignmentX(jDesktopPane1.getAlignmentX()-160);
    jDesktopPane1.add(sold);

}
```

[image: en el lado derecho se ve como no se ajusta bien al desktopPane]

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es centrar un jPanel  podrias utilizar la clase Dimension que representa el ancho en la dimensión de un componente.
Y utilizar el siguiente codigo.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
System.out.println("Tu resolución es de " + screenSize.width + "x" + screenSize.height);

Dimension pantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
jPanel.setSize(pantalla.width / 2, pantalla.height / 2);
```

Comment: pero el jpanel lo estoy agregando al desktopPane  y no se centra bien esto sirve para eso?